# Dropdown list/Combo box - Select values + textbox functionality (ASP.NET MVC / JQuery)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I'm looking for a dropdown box or combobox which allows the user to select a value from the list or type their own.
Does anyone have any suggestions for the above which is visually appealing and functional? I'm using ASP.NET MVC and JQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with the [jQuery UI library](http://jqueryui.com/), there's an example at [this page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/combobox.html).

It's a combination of the Button, ComboBox and Autocomplete elements included in the library.

**UPDATE**

You can find an example of how to do this without the autocomplete function on [this page](http://jonathan.tang.name/files/jquery_combobox/demo.html)

Specifically the `autoShow` option that widget provides will stop the autocomplete from dropping down while typing

Comment: I looked at that example. It functions as I want except I don't want the autocomplete in this case. I couldn't figure out how to disable the autocomplete while keeping the drop down list. Any ideas?

Comment: Yup there is one out there, I've posted a link in the original answer above